# Frobenius nearest non-negative Gram matrix of balanced row-sums

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Let $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be any non-negative real symmetric matrix. For $k \leq n$, let $\mathcal{F} := \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} \ | \ X \geq 0, X \mathbf{1} = \alpha \mathbf{1}, \alpha > 0\}$, i.e., the set of all entrywise non-negative $n \times k$-matrices having all row sums equal (for an *arbitrary* $\alpha > 0$). How can one determine

$$\arg\min_{X \in \mathcal{F}} \|W - X X^T\|_2^2 \quad,$$

i.e., the squared Frobenius nearest matrix to $W$ among all Gram matrices of the form $X X^T$ for $X \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Morally, I expect that this should be hard, since you're essentially trying to find the closest [completely positive matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyPositiveMatrix.html) to $W$, which is NP-hard.

In practice, I believe what people do is use approximations to the set of completely positive matrices that can be implemented by semidefinite programming.